# Lost data on orientation change in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a view pager with multi Fragments and my viewPager adapter is:

```
private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {

    MyPagerAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fragmentManager, @NonNull Lifecycle lifecycle) {
        super(fragmentManager, lifecycle);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = ScreenFragment.newInstance(position);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 5;
    }

}
```

In Fragments, When user changes orientation, I lost all data, and Fragment creates again. I added `setRetainInstance(true);` to onCreate method of Fragment and set `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"` to Activity line in manifest. But my problem still occurs.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

Changing the orientation of a device is considered a [configuration change](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes).

Configuration changes will destroy, and then re-create your fragments.

The recommended way to go about this problem is to use a [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModel). The idea of a ViewModel is that it survives these configuration changes, and when your Fragment is re-created, it will just reconnect to the ViewModel.

Alternatively, you can [handle the configuration change yourself](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes#HandlingTheChange). Google does not recommend this option, and is to be used as a last resort.

Comment: For use ViewModel, Should I use MVVM architecture? Or can it be used with ordinary coding?

Comment: If you can, you should try use the MVVM architecture. Doing so is the new 'gold standard' of android development, and highly recommended by Google themselves. You can [read more about it here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide)

Comment: My project is over and I only have this problem. It's a little difficult for me...

Answer (score 0):

You can save data and restore them after rotation.

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState, PersistableBundle outPersistentState) 
   {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState, outPersistentState);

    outState.putString("theWord", theWord); // Saving the Variable theWord
    outState.putStringArrayList("fiveDefns", fiveDefns); // Saving the ArrayList 
 fiveDefns
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle 
persistentState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState, persistentState);

    theWord = savedInstanceState.getString("theWord"); // Restoring theWord
    fiveDefns = savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList("fiveDefns"); //Restoring 
fiveDefns
}
```

Comment: in my fragments are web-views and I cant save web-views data.

Comment: no use cant save that data but you can save the state so that it can start from there. On the other hand you should use mvvm  so that you will be easy to manage.